# Change Grid Visibility property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP.

I have this xaml:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <GridView   x:Name="OrdersGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Grid  Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="667" Margin="415,53,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="867">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    </Grid>





</Grid>
```

I set `DetailGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed` to this grid `<Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"`  in `.cs`

I need to change it to `Visible` when I click on element in GridView.

How I can do it?

Thank's for help dudes.

Comment: Which element you want to handle click event? Since you know how to hide grid, what problem are you facing to show it back? Did you try `Visibility.Visible` to show it back?

Comment: Grid in grid view @SivaGopal

Comment: I think your question is not clear, pls correct it if required. You said "i set `DetailGrid.Visibility` to `Collapsed`" and want to change IT back to `Visible`.

Comment: I need to change it to Visible when I click on element in GridView.


This in my question tells that I need to click `Grid ` in `GridView`and change property of `Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"`. @SivaGopal

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to question

here is xaml:

```
   <GridView   x:Name="OrdersGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="True"

          SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="OrdersGridView_ItemClick" 
           >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Grid x:Name="GridInf" Tapped="Grid_Tapped"  Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="667" Margin="415,53,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="867">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="390,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    </Grid>
```

Here is code for activity:

```
 private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DetailGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

XAML: Add selection changed eventhandler

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <GridView   x:Name="OrdersGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Selection_Changed="OrdersGridView_SelectionChanged">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Grid  Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And the c# Code:

```
private void OrdersGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DetailGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```